# Magento attribute doesnt show in view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem. i want to show a attribute with shipping times on my product page. Now i want to show them under my pricing and above my short discription. I want to make sure that it will stand there as following:

[image]

I have placed the code in the addto.phtml section but it needs to show in the view.phtml section. If i edit anything in view.phtml then i does not show up. Even a simple test doesnt show up.

I think it is getting overruled by another page or file. How can i find out? Using following code in addto.phtml

[image: code]

I think that code needs to go here in the view.phtml file:

[image]

It does not show up if i use it there. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you file is wrong .Just to enable template from admin. check the location.Or Cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento-1.9, Display the custom attribute settings

**Magento Admin Panel** -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add Attribute ->

and **Frontend Properties** -> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end -> Yes

Once you can try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with your own template file that get loaded in the layout and called by view.phtml with the getChildHtml method.

Do you know about 'local.xml'? Here is a tutorial to get you up to speed:

http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

Note in the example this line:

```
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>addto</name></action>
```

Your local.xml needs the lines that go around that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.delivery" as="delivery" template="catalog/product/view/product_delivery.phtml"/>
            ...
```

In the template, in your theme, template folder with path catalog/product/view/product_delivery.phtml you can just enter `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>` to see if your template is rendering in the correct place. Later you can do whatever you need to in order to get the attribute data.

Now in your view.phtml, where you have your 'add to' line add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('delivery') ?>` and see if it loads on the front end. Obviously you need to make sure you have no caching on. If all has worked you should now see 'HELLO WORLD' - the template pulls through with no data, just the filler text.
You can now pull though your attribute in the template. It is the same class as the main view.phtml and the 'product' is available to be worked with. Check the other templates called by view.phtml as to how this is done.